# google cloud endpoints api_method not found on gke

Tags: flask, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

**404 response `Method: 1.api_endpoints_gcp_project_cloud_goog.Postoperation failed: NOT_FOUND` on google cloud endpoints esp**

I'm trying to deploy my API with google cloud endpoints with my backend over GKE. I'm getting this error on the Produced API logs, where shows:

`Method: 1.api_endpoints_gcp_project_cloud_goog.Postoperation failed: NOT_FOUND`

and i'm getting a 404 responde from the endpoint.

The backend container is answering correctly, but when i try to post http://[service-ip]/v1/postoperation i get the 404 error. I'm guessing it's related with the api_method name but i've already changed so it's the same in the openapi.yaml, the gke deployment and the app.py.

I deployed the API service succesfully with this openapi.yaml:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "API rest"
  title: "API example"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "api.endpoints.gcp-project.cloud.goog"
basePath: "/v1"
# [END swagger]
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
schemes:
# Uncomment the next line if you configure SSL for this API.
#- "https"
- "http"
paths:
  "/postoperation":
    post:
      description: "Post operation 1"
      operationId: "postoperation"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "success"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Model"
        400:
          description: "Error"
      parameters:
      - description: "Description"
        in: body
        name: payload
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Resource"

definitions:
  Resource:
    type: "object"
    required:
    - "text"
    properties:
      tipodni:
        type: "string"
      dni:
        type: "string"
      text:
        type: "string"

  Model:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      tipodni:
        type: "string"
      dni:
        type: "string"
      text:
        type: "string"
      mundo:
        type: "string"
      cluster:
        type: "string"
      equipo:
        type: "string"
      complejidad:
        type: "string"
```

Then i tried to configure the backend and esp with this deploy.yaml and lb-deploy.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
  namespace: development
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api1
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api1
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          secret:
            secretName: secret-key

      containers:
      - name: api-container
        image: gcr.io/gcp-project/docker-pqr:IMAGE_TAG_PLACEHOLDER
        volumeMounts:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          mountPath: /var/secrets/google
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000

      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
        args: [
          "--http_port=8081",
          "--backend=127.0.0.1:5000",
          "--service=api.endpoints.gcp-project.cloud.goog",
          "--rollout_strategy=managed"
        ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081

kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "api1-lb"
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  #  loadBalancerIP: "172.30.33.221"
  selector:
    app: api1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8081
```

my flask app that serves the api, is this app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

categorizador = Categorizador(model_properties.paths)

@app.route('/postoperation', methods=['POST'])
def postoperation():

    text = request.get_json().get('text', '')
    dni = request.get_json().get('dni', '')
    tipo_dni = request.get_json().get('tipo_dni', '')

    categoria,subcategoria = categorizador.categorizar(text)

    content = {
        'tipodni': tipo_dni,
        'dni': dni,
        'text': text,
        'mundo': str(categoria),
        'cluster': str(subcategoria),
        'equipo': '',
        'complejidad': ''
    }

    return jsonify(content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure route in your flask app.
Try this:

```
@app.route('/v1/postoperation', methods=['POST'])
```

Comment: That's why i'm using basePath: "/v1" on openapi.yaml. As i said, the backend is anwsering correctly, i think the problem might be with the esp.

Comment: I don't think this 'basePath' url automatically propagates to flask route. This is just a schema, and it should be repeated inside your actual app. At least it worked for me like this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/versioning-an-api

Comment: I removed the basePath and it's working correctly. It seems like the issue it's when i try to version it.

Comment: Yes, either remove it or add it to handlers in app yaml file, that's how it worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Some bits from `kubectl expose -h`

- `--port=''` - The port that the service should serve on. Copied from the resource being exposed, if unspecified
- `--target-port=''` - Name or number for the port on the container that the service should direct traffic to.
  Optional.

While proxy directing your trafic to `--backend=127.0.0.1:5000`, use container name isntead `--backend=api-container:5000`.

Comment: i'm defining both port and target port on the service yaml. Actually i have no communication issues between containers, when i curl from the esp to 127.0.0.1 i get a correct answer